# Why useEffect is triggering without dependency change?

Tags: react-native, use-effect

I wanted only when I setCart to trigger useEffect. But this is not happening:

```
import React from 'react'
import { View } from 'react-native'

const CartScreen = () => {

    const [cart, setCart] = React.useState([])

    React.useEffect(() => {
        console.log('test');
    }, [cart])

    return (
        <View>
        </View>
    )
}

export default CartScreen;
```

Output: test

it fires without even having touched the cart state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

useEffect will always run the first time when your component is rendered. If you only want some code to run after you change the state you can just have an if statement to check that

```js
import React from 'react'
import { View } from 'react-native'

const CartScreen = () => {
    const [cart, setCart] = React.useState([])

    React.useEffect(() => {
        if(cart.length > 0)
            console.log('test')
    }, [cart])

    return (
        <View>
        </View>
    )
}

export default CartScreen;
```